# How do i deserialize a json to an object? My attemts end up with an JObject and not an object with my properties. How do i avoid this?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, dynamic

I want to convert something like this this `{\"ref\":\"/my/path\",\"action\":\"set\",\"payload\":\"\"}`

into a generic object in C#. What i tried is this

```
object  mess1 = JObject.Parse(message);
dynamic mess2 =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(message);
dynamic mess3 = JValue.Parse(message);
```

The expected result would be an object with the properties ref, action and set. The actual result is an object containing the JObject

ChildrenTokens
Count
First
HasValues
Last
Next
Parent
...

these are not part of my object. What is the correct way of doing this?

The payload in this message is a string OR an arbitrary object. The payload is to be written to a database and i do not care what it contains.

Comment: These are the Properties of `JObject` not in your json. Show your code.

Comment: You can use something like JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourModel>(Your JSON string); Or Add proper Json/JObject data into question.So, understand easily.

Answer (score 0):

`JObject.Parse` generates a `JObject` instance. You can do this a couple of ways, if you already have `JObject`, you can do the following:

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
var command = obj.ToObject<Command>();
```

Or, you can work from the string:

```
var command = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Command>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize it into a dynamic object with:

```
 dynamic parsed = JObject.Parse("ref\":\"/my/path\",\"action\":\"set\",\"payload\":\"\");
```

And access your properties like any other object:

```
Console.WriteLine(parsed.ref); // "/my/path/"
Console.WriteLine(parsed.action); // "set"
Console.WriteLine(parsed.payload); // "\"
```

Comment: I do not want to have a specfic type in this case. In javascript i can simply do 
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonstring); there has to be something like this in C# too?

Comment: Okay. I edited my answer to deserialize it to a dynamic object and not a concrete class.

Comment: dynamic parsed = JObject.Parse("{\"ref\":\"/my/path\",\"action\":\"set\",\"payload\":\"\"}"); will convert it into a JObject instead of an object with the properties ref, set and payload. The reason for not wanting to convert it into a specific class is that payload on this object is an arbitrary object. I don't care what it contains, it is to be written to a database.

Answer (score 0):

We generally use 
this method

```
public static JObject JsonParsed(string Json)
    {
        return JObject.Parse(Json);
    }
```

Comment: But that gives me a JObject? and i can not access the properties ref, action or payload on the object.

Answer (score 0):

By "object with my properties" you mean what's often referred as [POCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_CLR_object).
You have to define a POCO object like so:

```
public class Poco  
{
  public string Ref { get; set; }
  public string Action { get; set; }
  public string Payload { get; set; }  
}
```

Then deserialize your JSON like so:

```
 string json = "{'ref':'/my/path','action':'set','payload':''}";
 Poco myPoco = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Poco>(json);
```

Now you will have `myPoco.Ref`, `myPoco.Action`, `myPoco.Payload` properties populated from your JSON.